# Difficulty in decoding the Prufer code.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, algorithms

I was looking at the proof of the following result:

> Let $n\geq 2$,the number of spanning trees in the complete graph $K_n$ is $n^{n-2}$.

The proof uses a bijection between $T$ ,the set of all spanning trees of $K_n$ and $A$, the set of all sequences $(a_1,a_2,...,a_{n-2})$ with $1\leq a_i\leq n$ for all $i$.The bijection is given by the Prufer code.

The forward map is clear to me.

We will look at all leaf nodes and pick the one with minimal numbering.Then we will delete the vertex and the associated edge and take a note of the neighboring vertex/node.We will continue in this way and finally we will end up getting two nodes connected with one edge.Thus we obtain $(a_1,a_2,...,a_{n-2})$.

For example,look at the following graph:

[image]

Then following the algorithm we get something like:

[image]

So,the Prufer sequence is $(1,8,3,1,4,4,8)$.

Now I am having problem in decoding the sequence and forming a tree.

The algorithm is to choose minimal $b_1\notin (a_1,a_2,...,a_{n-2})$ and join $b_1a_1$.Then take minimal $b_2\neq b_1 $ and $b_2\notin (a_2,a_3,...,a_{n-2})$ and join $b_2a_2$ ,then take minimal $b_3\neq b_1,b_2$ and $b_2\notin (a_3,a_4,...,a_{n-2})$ and join $b_3a_3$ and proceed in this way.

But applying this algorithm on $(1,8,3,1,4,4,8)$,I am not getting the same tree.

Can someone tell me where I am making the mistake?

Comment: Well, your Prüfer code is correct, so it's hard to tell where you're making a mistake in the part of your work that you did not show :)

Comment: From your description, it's possible that you're missing an initial step: before you begin this algorithm, you should append $n$ (in this case, $9$) to the Prüfer code, getting $(1,8,3,1,4,4,8,9)$.

Comment: @MishaLavrov But why should I append $9$ then the sequence will no longer be an $n-2$ length sequence.

Comment: @MishaLavrov Can you please show me the steps of decoding by drawing pictures?

Comment: A didactic example [here](https://web.math.ucsb.edu/~adeboye/137A_II/Homework%204-Solutions%20copy.pdf)

Comment: @JeanMarie Thank you,I have to append the number not in the list to the tail of the list along with removing the head of the list.